# Calculating nearest neighbor distances

Tags: atoms, crystal-structure, solid-state-chemistry

For cubic materials, there are equations in which to calculate nearest neighbor (NN), second nearest neighbor, etc. Can this be done with tetragonal crystal structures? I want to calculate NN, 2NN, and 3NN of $\ce{TiO2}$ rutile with a tetragonal crystal structure but am unsure how to do it. Any suggestions/help would be appreciated!

[image]

Comment: There is no equation for cubic materials. What you probably have in mind is the formula for the _simple cubic_ structure having **one** atom per unit cell. Rutile is very much not like that. True, it is tetragonal, but to say that is the same as to say nothing. You will need atomic coordinates, symmetry elements, and on top of that, some textbook on crystallography. Then (and not before) you'll have your first distances, etc.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Could I just use coordination analysis to create the radial distribution function and take the first peak for 1NN, second peak for 2NN, etc?

Comment: It depends on what do you mean by coordination analysis.

Comment: @IvanNeretin If I create the RDF of my material, it is sufficient to use that to calculate the NN distances right?

Comment: Well, then these are just different ways to say the same thing. How are you going to create an RDF?

Comment: @IvanNeretin I have software to create the RDF of my system. Forget about how I calculate it. I am just asking: IF I have the RDF, I can take the first peak as 1NN, 2nd peak as 2NN correct?

Comment: Yeah, kinda like that. Wait a sec. You ***do*** realize that rutile contains two types of atoms and their environments (and hence RDFs around them) are quite different, right?

Comment: @IvanNeretin Yes I realize that they are made up of oxygen and Titanium atoms. Essentially I want to perform some sort of cluster analysis on an irradiated model, and most of what I have read defines the spacing between certain types of defects in a crystal given their 2NN distance. With two atom types, how would you go about calculating 2NN?

Comment: Like I said before: look up the atomic coordinates, symmetry elements, and _then_ draw the diagram manually, or maybe rely on the software.

Comment: @IvanNeretin I just added the RDF into my question. I would interpret this to mean that 3NN = ~2.5 Angstorms, whereas 1NN and 2NN are around 1.9-2

Comment: What kind of interatomic distances are included in this RDF? Ti-O, Ti-Ti, O-O, or all of the above?

Comment: @IvanNeretin All of the Above

Comment: Then probably the distances around 1.9-2 are Ti-O, the next peak is O-O (which is altogether irrelevant if you want the neighbors of Ti!), then goes Ti-Ti, or maybe another O-O... see, it is not that simple, after all.

Comment: @IvanNeretin So I took your advance and looked at the crystal. I see that 1.94 and 1.98 peaks correspond to O-Ti, 2.5 peak is O-O, 2.7 peak is also O-O, 2.9 peak is Ti-Ti. I do not have a lot of experience using NN. How would you go about choosing what cutoff distance to use?

Answer (score 4):

First, you can obtain [CIF-file from COD](http://www.crystallography.net/cod/9015662.html), then load it with [Olex2](http://www.olexsys.org/) (free, available on Windows, Linux, MacOS) and execute command `envi <r>`, which will print a list of the atoms about special position within a sphere of radius $r$. For example, `envi 3` ($r = \pu{3 Å}$) yields in the following assigned pairs:

```
    O    SYMM  Ti    Ti    Ti    O     O     O     O     O     O     O     O     O     O     O
Ti  1.95 1_554 -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -
Ti  1.95 I     98.8  -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -
Ti  1.98 2_544 130.6 130.6 -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -
O   2.54 4_454 49.4  49.4  180.0 -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -
O   2.78 1_544 93.4  150.2 44.5  135.5 -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -
O   2.78 1_545 150.2 93.4  44.5  135.5 64.4  -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -
O   2.78 3_655 150.2 93.4  44.5  135.5 89.1  54.3  -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -
O   2.78 3_654 93.4  150.2 44.5  135.5 54.3  89.1  64.4  -     -     -     -     -     -     -
O   2.78 1_554 45.5  96.2  117.2 62.8  111.5 159.1 106.5 73.5  -     -     -     -     -     -
O   2.78 I     96.2  45.5  117.2 62.8  159.1 111.5 73.5  106.5 64.4  -     -     -     -     -
O   2.78 3_554 45.5  96.2  117.2 62.8  73.5  106.5 159.1 111.5 90.9  125.7 -     -     -     -
O   2.78 3_555 96.2  45.5  117.2 62.8  106.5 73.5  111.5 159.1 125.7 90.9  64.4  -     -     -
O   2.96 2_543 40.6  139.4 90.0  90.0  57.8  122.2 122.2 57.8  57.8  122.2 57.8  122.2 -     -
O   2.96 2_545 139.4 40.6  90.0  90.0  122.2 57.8  57.8  122.2 122.2 57.8  122.2 57.8  180.0 -
```

---

But this is only based on our guess for allowed $r$ value and is rather speculative. Answering your secondary question from the comments – "How would you go about choosing what cutoff distance to use?" – I would suggest to use Voronoi-Dirichlet (VD) polyhedra set [1] for every crystallographically inequivalent atom (e.g. for Ti and O pair in this case). You can do it with the [ToposPro](http://topospro.com/) (Free, available on Windows), using `Dirichlet` subroutine.

#### Titanium:

```
Central atom:Ti1 0.500 0.500 0.500 Rsd:1.220
Atom:1.949 < r < 3.487  <r>=2.570   Top: 1.621 < R < 1.785  <R>=1.742
CN=6:0:4 NV=16 V=7.607/20.812 S=23.299 Cpac=0.509 Ccov=3.131
G3=0.083992444
Face distribution: {3/4 6/6 }
Vertex distribution: {3/16 }

  N  Atom   x      y      z     Dist.  SAng. 
  1  O  1  0.3048  0.3048  1.0000  1.94857  16.77659
  2  O  1  0.6952  0.6952  1.0000  1.94857  16.77659
  3  O  1  0.3048  0.3048  0.0000  1.94857  16.77659
  4  O  1  0.6952  0.6952  0.0000  1.94857  16.77659
  5  O  1  0.1952  0.8048  0.5000  1.98000  16.44522
  6  O  1  0.8048  0.1952  0.5000  1.98000  16.44522
 *7  O  1 -0.1952  0.1952  0.5000  3.48704   0.00080
 *8  O  1  0.8048  1.1952  0.5000  3.48704   0.00080
 *9  O  1  0.1952 -0.1952  0.5000  3.48704   0.00080
*10  O  1  1.1952  0.8048  0.5000  3.48704   0.00080
```

VD-polyhedra for Ti atom with NN denoted with the bonds:

[image]

#### Oxygen:

```
Central atom:O1 0.305 0.305 0.000 Rsd:1.413
 D(CP):0.050  ( 0.2971 0.2971 -0.0000 )
 D(VDP):0.069  ( 0.2941 0.2941 -0.0000 )
Atom:1.949 < r < 3.487  <r>=2.788   Top: 1.621 < R < 1.820  <R>=1.747
CN=6:8:4 NV=32 V=11.805/52.029 S=28.544 Cpac=0.328 Ccov=2.138
G3=0.085774387
Face distribution: {3/4 6/14 }
Vertex distribution: {3/32 }

  N  Atom   x      y      z     Dist.  SAng. 
  1  Ti 1  0.5000  0.5000 -0.5000  1.94857  16.77659
  2  Ti 1  0.5000  0.5000  0.5000  1.94857  16.77659
  3  Ti 1  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  1.98000  16.44522
  4  O  1  0.6952  0.6952  0.0000  2.53648   3.12774
 #5  O  1  0.8048  0.1952 -0.5000  2.77800   4.78494
 #6  O  1  0.1952 -0.1952 -0.5000  2.77800   4.78494
 #7  O  1  0.8048  0.1952  0.5000  2.77800   4.78494
 #8  O  1  0.1952  0.8048 -0.5000  2.77800   4.78494
 #9  O  1 -0.1952  0.1952 -0.5000  2.77800   4.78494
#10  O  1  0.1952  0.8048  0.5000  2.77800   4.78494
#11  O  1  0.1952 -0.1952  0.5000  2.77800   4.78494
#12  O  1 -0.1952  0.1952  0.5000  2.77800   4.78494
*13  O  1  0.3048  0.3048 -1.0000  2.95870   1.71934
*14  O  1  0.3048  0.3048  1.0000  2.95870   1.71934
 15  O  1  0.6952 -0.3048  0.0000  3.32530   2.57704
 16  O  1 -0.3048  0.6952  0.0000  3.32530   2.57704
*17  Ti 1  1.0000  0.0000  0.0000  3.48704   0.00080
*18  Ti 1  0.0000  1.0000  0.0000  3.48704   0.00080
```

VD-polyhedra for O atom with NN denoted with the bonds:

[image]

Briefly, we are looking for interactions that are not labeled with # or *; to sum it up, there are the following sets of NN:

- 6 NN for Ti: 4×O@1.94857 Å, 2×O@1.98000 Å;
- 6 NN for O: 2×Ti@1.94857 Å, 1×Ti@1.98000 Å, 1×O@2.53648 Å, 2×O@3.32530 Å.

#### Reference

1. Blatov, V. A.; Shevchenko, A. P.; Serenzhkin, V. N. *Acta Cryst A*, **1995**, 51 (6), 909–916 DOI: [10.1107/S0108767395006799](https://doi.org/10.1107/S0108767395006799).

Comment: I really appreciate this detailed answer of calculating the different NN distances. Is there a general consensus on which one of these to use for cluster analysis of a given property? Each value will produce vastly different results.

Comment: Also In this case, the 2nd nearest neighbor for Titanium would be 1.98, and for Oxygen would be 2.53 correct?

Comment: I always relied on VD-approach for this matter. It provides algorithmic, descriptive and unambiguous result.

Comment: @JacksonHart Oh, my bad, I posted wrong number in conclusion for O (already fixed, listing was correct). It is 1.98 both for Ti and O.

Comment: I am not sure that VD would work in my case. First, I have to use WS analysis to calculate vacancies, and then I want to determine the size of clustering of vacancies. So I need to load in the MD dump file, perform WS analysis, and then specify the cutoff distance between vacancies, which would form a void.

Comment: Also, you use 6NN as 6 nearest neighbors. In this case though, wouldnt the second nearest neigbor for O atoms be 1.98, or do you say 1.94 because there is more than 1 atom with this distance? Just not sure the interpretation of the scientific jargon

Comment: @JacksonHart Well, it may be not your cup of tea then, but keep in mind that VD approach is rather universal (e.g. nothing prevents you from doing the same for MOFs and molecular clusters) and system-agnostic; all you need is an established structure.

Comment: @JacksonHart Yes, I treat atoms with same $r$ as equivalent, so what I mean by 2NN is the atom with higher $r$ (second subshell, if it can be called so).

Comment: Can VD filter out non-defect atoms? Is there a WS subroutine that I can run first?

Comment: @JacksonHart What does WS in WS-analysis stand for, for me to be 100% sure we are on the same page?

Comment: Sorry, Wigner-Seitz Defect Analysis to determine vacancies and clusters. If I just look at my lattice, one of the Ti-Ti distance is ~4.5 Angstroms. They are next to each other though and just one unit cell over. If they were both missing, they should be a cluster. Maybe I should choose this distance. Could you extend the radius of the analysis you ran so I can see just a bit further out?

Comment: @JacksonHart Sorry, I'm unfamiliar with WS analysis and I'm afraid I cannot give you a direct answer whether ToposPro is the right tool for you except for suggesting to read the [manual](http://topospro.com/download/manuals/topos_practical_manual_112.pdf) (sorry for RTFMing you:( ) Regarding the radius, in Olex2 you can use any number you want (e.g. `envi 5` in your case), but in VD method it's pointless as it relies on solid angle values of VD-polyhedra for a given atom. If the atom is "cut-offed" (as here, as $\Omega(\ce{Ti-Ti})=0$), then it's considered as non-bonded atom

Comment: @JacksonHart But sure, if you have a structure with vacancies, then you get different environment and totally different picture in solid angle distribution, possibly resulting in Ti-Ti interaction (vdW, I suspect).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66899/discussion-between-andselisk-and-jackson-hart).

Comment: I see, just makes it hard determining a cutoff distance for a diatomic system to define what a cluster of defects is. For instance, how far do to vacancies have to be before they are not considered a cluster? These questions are already hard to answer in monotomic systems, and more challenging in diatomic

Comment: I already mentioned in the chat that WS-analysis is turned out to be pretty much the same as VD-analysis, I just never seen this name before (shame on me) :D. regarding the cluster stuff, it looks like a separate question to me, I also not quite sure how to answer it shortly – I don't know the uniform criteria either, sorry.

Comment: @JacksonHart I just checked the manual, and yes, another subroutine called `IsoCryst` from ToposPro can do what you want: "*Analysis of molecular crystals, including H-bonded ones and supramolecular complexes. Searching for clusters (also of nano-size) in intermetallides and other structures.*"